# Drawing a straight line averaging a curve

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I would like to draw a straight line that makes the average of a curve. I am plotting my data like that:

```
plot 'dataset' u 2:4 w p smooth bezier
```

My data consists of multiple columns and I would get something like that:[image]

Any ideas of how to do it? I guess it is more an interpolation than an average. It is not relevant the ups and downs of the curve, and it would be much better to have a straight line interpolating the curve...

Using a straight line could be more or less easy to fit using `fit` however, how could I fit a curve that does not look like a well know curve? Let me show you an example? How could I fit a smooth curve among the main group of points? Please notice that there is some noise on the lower part of the graph that I wouldn't like to represent.
[image]

Comment: Assuming you have the values that created this plot why don't you just find the average and plot it along side this plot?  Disclaimer: I've never worked with gnuplot.

Comment: @ Florin Stingaciu How could I calculate the average of the curve?Maybe fitting could be the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do some basic statistics on your data, gnuplot has a builtin command [`stats`](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/stats.html) which may do what you want.  Gnuplot offers some internal variables after plotting that contain data about min, max, etc.  To see what these are, type `show variables all` after plotting your data.

Otherwise if you want to fit your data to a line, gnuplot does that as well:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) 'data.dat' using 2:4 via a,b
plot 'data.dat' using 2:4, f(x)
```

Comment: @ andyras that is what I was looking for. The problem is I need to plot several curves and fitting them to f(x) just plot one line, the last one I've fitted. It would be good if I could do it for every single curve so I could represent them all together

Comment: @Manolete -- I'm confused.  What lines do you want on your final plot?  Do you want multiple curves + 1 fit line?  multiple curves and multiple fits?  only a fit?

Comment: I've got 4 curves and I would like to plot 4 fits all together

Comment: @Manolete -- Are you using gnuplot4.6?  If thats the case, `stats` is definitely the way to go.  `stats 'dset1' u 1:2; a1=STATS_slope;b1=STATS_intercept ...` and then `plot 'dset1' u 1:2, a1*x+b1, 'dset2' u 1:2, a2*x+b2, ...`.  Also note that stats uses a better fitting algorithm for a linear-regression than `fit` since `fit` needs to be able to fit any (non-linear or linear) function.

Comment: I am currently using version 4.2